# cancatenar dos variables tipo datetime en una url con ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

quiero concatenar dos variables tipo datetime en una url con ajax y no se como estructurar la url, si alguien me puede ayudar por favor dejo una porcion del codigo que estoy usando...

```
<script>
    function cargarData() {
            var datos = {};
            datos.desde = desde.option('value');
            datos.hasta = hasta.option('value');

            $.ajax({                
                url: rutaApi + "visita/" + desde,
                method: "GET",
                data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (!data.error) {                       
                        $("#grdConsultas").dxDataGrid({
                            dataSource: data,
                            "export": {
                                enabled: true,
                                fileName: "Visitas",
                                allowExportSelectedData: true,
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

adjunto a esto debo concatenar la otra variable que seria hasta

```
url: rutaApi + "visita/" + desde,
```

soy novato en el ambiente de programacion web espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Por qué querés enviar el desde y hasta por url? Pregunto porque ya lo mandás antes en `data: JSON.stringify(datos)` como `GET`.

Comment: Cual es el resultado final que esperas??

Comment: lo que quiero es mostrar los datos que se almacenan en la base de datos y que con esa url mostrarla en un grid

Comment: mira lo que quiero es simple el codigo me funciona perfecto lo unico que quiero es concatenar dos varaibles a la url por ejemplo algo asi

Comment: pero no me ah funcionado asi por eso consulto como concatenar esas variables

Comment: `url: rutaApi + "visita/desde/hasta"`

Comment: esa es la estructura que busco pero no funciona si lo coloco asi porque son datos que tomaria de un textbox

Comment: Estaría bueno que dejes un ejemplo de ruta válida.. por lo que te entendí sería así `var url_concatenada = rutaApi + 'visita/' + desde + '/' + hasta` y luego en `ajax url: url_concatenada, //......` Sin embargo es una práctica un poco extraña la que estas aplicando..

Comment: lo resolvi en mi service de visita y luego desarrolle dos variables para la entrada de las fechas de esa forma pude trabajar en mis reportes gracias a todos por sus aportes